# "since you have kids" or since "you have had kids"

Tags: present-perfect

*Do you think your relationship with your wife has changed since **you have kids**?*

I am not sure whether the tense in the bold part is used correct. I would use the present perfect (you have had kids).

Comment: ***have had*** is syntactically fine there, but native speakers would often go for the simpler form *...since **having** kids* (more verbosely, *...since **having had** kids*).

Comment: @FumbleFinger Since having had kids is simpler than since you've had kids??

Comment: @Lambie: I said the simpler form *...since **having** kids.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, "since" has two possible meanings:

> 1. **because of** [something]
> 2. **dating from** [some event]

"Since *you have* kids" implies the first meaning.  "Since *you've had* kids" implies the second meaning.

Both are correct -- it all depends on which, precisely, you want to say:

> Do you think your relationship [is different] because you **have** kids?
>
> Do you think your relationship [has become different] dating from the time you **had** kids?

As FumbleFingers' comment mentions, there are other idiomatic ways to phrase the question, which are just variations on the second option.

> Has your relationship changed since **having** kids?
>
> Has your relationship changed since **having had** kids?

Answer (score 0):

Present perfect (**since you have had kids**) is apt there, but a good many native speakers would not use it, and would say *...now that you have kids* or *...since you have kids* taking **since** in its causative sense, not as a temporal.

Comment: People say things many ways in English. It is perfectly natural for a person to say: Now that you've had kids, [etc.] or Since you've had kids. Many native speakers would say that.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the most **natural sounding ways to say** this are:
Since you've had kids
Since you've passed the bar exam
Since you've seen the evidence

Question: Do you think your relationship with your wife has changed **since you have kids?**

Comment:  Strictly speaking, as written, **since there would have to be because in order to be grammatical.**

But native speakers generally would use contracted forms here in English.

**You don't go out since you have kids**. has to mean because.
**You don't go out since you've had kids". the meaning is obvious. A point in time.

In speaking, for me, "I've [past participle]" with since is more natural as a time indicator. Not as natural but also **grammatical is: since having kids**. **I would write that more than I would tend to say.** Or I would use it to tell a story (verbally or in writing).

"Look, since [because] you committed the crime, you have to pay the time."

That is how I tend to use since for because. It can only mean because there.

"Do you think your relationship with your wife has changed since [because] you **have** kids?" **I would not use that to mean "because"**. I would say "because or since you've had kids". With the verb have had.

Comment: I'd have to disagree with your "because|since" prescription. Native speakers use **since** to introduce a clause expressing a reason or cause all the time.

Comment: I'm referring to your "Strictly speaking ... [the word] "since" there would have to be "because" in order to be grammatical". [my quotes]

Comment: I thought you were saying that the word "since" would have to be changed to "because".  I misunderstood the word **be**. But the site won't allow me to remove the downvote unless you make some edit.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Actually, you can, it is just tricky. I removed one the other day. Just keep playing with it. It will return to zero.